# Initialize stdarray with size depending on const class member

Tags: c++, stdarray

Can somebody explain to me why the following results in the error "non-type template argument is not a constant expression" and how to deal with it?

```
#include <array>

class Test
{
    public:
    Test(int n) : num_requests(n/2){};
    const int num_requests;
    
    void func()
    {
        std::array <int,num_requests> test_array;
    };
};
```

Comment: Template parameter must be a compile time constant. `num_requests` is not known at compile time, you cannot use it.

Comment: One possibility is to template your `class Test`. Another possibility is to use a `std::vector>` instead of a `std::array`.

Comment: The code for templates is created at compile time, thats why it will no be sufficient for the variable to be const. It must be a constexpr, which means that the compiler can determine the value of the variable (at compile time). And for example template arguments are constexpr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a template "argument" [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/7j4dTzKjf):

```cpp
#include <array>

template <int n>
struct Test
{
    void func()
    {
        std::array <int,n/2> test_array;
    };
};

int main() {
    auto t = Test<10>{};
    t.func();
}
```

Comment: removed the comments. I still wonder why clang accepted it. Maybe worth another question. I am used to gcc being more lax, but here its clang that is a bit unexpected

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for pointing it out anyway. I was a bit surprised when it worked at first, but was to lazy to double check with another compiler.

Comment: problem was just that the method wasnt called in your code. Once you do that also clang reports the error: https://godbolt.org/z/fz3q9cfTx. I forgot once again that errors in methods of class templates do not necessarily show up unless they are actually instantiated

Comment: i added the call to your code, because its needed to actually demonstrate that it works

Comment: sorry, was too quick, now it should be fine, also godbolt link updated